# How to reset angular filter property

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of filtered data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:search:true">
    <td>
        <div>{{course.course_name}}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and a SELECT input to help filter it:

```
<select ng-model="search.location_id">
    <option value="">Location</option>
    <option ng-repeat="course in courses" value="{{course.location_id}}>{{course.location}}</option>
</select>
```

Everything works great when switching between course locations to filter the data. My problem is that when I want to show ALL of the data and return to the default SELECT option (value=""), the data is gone and interprets it as nothing matching instead of unsetting the filter.

I realize that if I use search:false, it will work as intended, but I need this parameter as true and I also need a way to reset the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-options` inside your `select` statement. You can leave the single `<option>` with `value=""` in there though. If you select the default option, the value of `search.location_id` will be `null`, which should be exactly what you need.

```
<select ng-model="search.location_id" ng-options="course.location for course in courses">
    <option value="">Location</option>
</select>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ShFi25) on Plunker.